# Which authentication library to use with Node.js for all Microsoft accounts

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I'm trying to create an Amazon Alexa service that will take advantage of the Microsoft Graph... This is built with Node.js.

Currently when using my standard Outlook.com Microsoft Account to sign in, I get redirected to a Microsoft page that says

> **Microsoft account is unavailable**
>
> Microsoft account is unavailable from this site, so you can't sign in or sign up. The site may be experiencing a problem.
>
> You can sign in or sign up at other Microsoft Sites and services, or try again later at this site.

I have been using `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize` as my authorization URL in the Alexa config account linking section. and using the Node [Microsoft Graph JavaScript SDK](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript) library in my code.

I'm wondering if the Node library I'm using is the correct one? Has it been deprecated?  Or is there something else going on here?

Comment: I assume you're able to signing to Outlook.com without a problem? Have you tried signing in to [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) with this account?

Comment: Hey @MarcLaFleur-MSFT yes I can sign into the graph explorer, i can use my outlook account and all other services that Microsoft offer with my standard microsoft account.

Comment: You mentioned MSAL in the tags, are you using https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js to handle the authentication workflow? If so, could you provide some code showing how you're using it?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT I mentioned MSAL because i'm unsure which is the right authentication library to use.  I'm currently using https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript but saw that this might be deprecated and that MSAL is being presented as the right authentication library.  but it seems MSAL isn't for Node.js applications?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A common misunderstanding with Microsoft Graph is the separation of concerns between the API and Authentication.

You do not actually authenticate against Microsoft Graph. Instead you authenticate against the directory that holds your account, for organizational accounts this is Active Directory and for consumer accounts this the Outlook.com.

Once you have authenticated, you use the token you received back to identify yourself when calling Microsoft Graph API.

This is where you (and many others) get tripped up at first. Just as there are two concerns (Auth & API), there are also two separate SDKs. For Node.js you're looking for:

- [Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/msal): This handles authentication for both Azure AD and Microsoft Accounts.

  `npm install msal`
- [Microsoft Graph JavaScript Client Library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client): This is the client library for Microsoft Graph. It will provide the objects and methods you need to simplify calling the APIs.

  `npm install @microsoft/microsoft-graph-client`

This should give you the tools you need to get started. There are some things around App Registration, OAUTH and Admin Consent that you'll likely run into as well. For these, you might find these helpful:

- [Microsoft v2 Endpoint Primer](http://massivescale.com/microsoft-v2-endpoint-primer/)
- [v2 Endpoint and Implicit Grant](http://massivescale.com/microsoft-v2-endpoint-implicit-grant/)
- [v2 Endpoint and Admin Consent](http://massivescale.com/microsoft-v2-endpoint-admin-consent/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Something odd happened with the last two. Fixed them.

Comment: It seems like MSAL is only for browsers? Is there a way to login via a backend call?

Comment: MSAL library for JavaScript is for client-side JS but there other MSAL flavors for other environments: https://github.com/AzureAD?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=msal&type=&language=